# Is there anywhere at Melbourne Airport to buy a Myki?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, melbourne, mel

I've had a read of the [Wikivoyage page for Melbourne airport](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Melbourne_Airport), and discovered the much much cheaper way into the city via the 901 bus to Broadmeadows then the train.

However, in order to do this route, I really need to get myself a [myki smart card](http://ptv.vic.gov.au/tickets/myki/). Looking on the [myki website](http://ptv.vic.gov.au/tickets/myki/) at the list of retailers and stations you can get one, there's no-where showing at/near the airport.

Is there somewhere not listed on the myki website which sells them at the airport?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is! But there aren't any signs to tell you...

As explained on the [PTV Airport Buses page](http://ptv.vic.gov.au/getting-around/airport-buses/), the SkyBus ticket office at the airport sells the [myki Visitor Value Pack](http://ptv.vic.gov.au/tickets/myki/myki-visitor-value-pack/). That costs $14, and comes with $8 credit (plus a few other bits).

There are no signs at the SkyBus ticket office about myki, it isn't listed on any of the prices shown, but if you queue up and ask they'll get one out of a secret drawer and sell one to you!

Once you've bought your myki, it's a moderately well signposted 1 minute walk to where the 901 bus goes from - follow the signs for Public Buses.

Alternately, there are in theory some regular myki topup and purchase machines in [T2, T3 and T4](http://ptv.vic.gov.au/news-and-events/news/myki-machines-installed-at-melbourne-airport/), but they're not well signed and rather hidden. You're looking for a silver/grey machine with a blue sign on the top. I couldn't find the T2 one, the T3 one is on the far left as you go to leave the baggage claim area by the toilets. For topping up a myki it may be worth hunting, though don't forget you can also top up on the bus! For visitors, heading to the SkyBus ticket office to buy one is likely to be much quicker and easier

Answer (score 11):

Thought I'd provide an update since these posts are all ~4 years old. There's no sign of a Myki station between Qantas domestic arrivals and and bus terminal (about a 5 minute walk). You can, however, purchase a Myki for $15 from any of the Skybus ticket kiosks. This includes $9 of credit and is ready to use immediately.

Comment: Welcome to the site Emmylou, this will be helpful for many people.

Answer (score 9):

You can actually buy a ticket on the bus itself.

I've done it, and as you can see on the official website, it is one of the published official outlets.

From: https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/tickets/myki/buy-a-myki-and-top-up/where-to-buy-and-top-up/

**Where you can buy a myki**

You can buy a myki

- At over 800 retail outlets including all 7-Eleven stores and selected
  retailers where you see the myki sign
- the ticket office window at Premium Stations
- online (link opens in a new window)
- by calling 1800 800 007 6am - midnight daily
- from a myki machine (full fare myki only) at all metropolitan train
  stations and V/Line commuter service train stations and selected
  accessible tram stops and bus interchanges
- PTV Hub
- **onboard buses**

EDIT: I'm not aware of any restrictions with regards to purchasing myki tickets on a bus. My understanding is that you can purchase any kind of ticket on any of the standard metropolitan buses. I.e - if the bus is not a regional (V-LINE) or charter-bus, you should be able to purchase Adult, Concession and Senior myki tickets. The tickets are differentiated with a single letter on one side and by the amount charged per journey.

Comment: Do you know if that applies to all buses, or only some?

Comment: @Gagravarr - I'm not aware of any and have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: When was this? I was in Melbourne in March this year (2014) and there was no option to buy it on the Bus (but the driver was nice enough to let us travel to the train station where we bought mykis.) As other answers have already said - you can buy the Visitor pack myki from the Skybus desk, or you can use the vending machine in the terminal.

Comment: This was in 2013, unless I'm mistaken. Since the bus is expected to carry tickets by the Public Transport Commission,  or whatever the organization is called now - the driver is required to let you on. Just like he/she is obligated to allow you to board in the event that the ticket reader/writer is defective.

Comment: @JamesS As you experienced - many drivers will just let you on if you explain the situation.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a vending machine within Melbourne airport where you can buy (and presumably top up) a myki.

Comment: I didn't spot it when looking for one last night - do you know where it is and/or what it looks like?

Comment: @Gagravarr not really sure, but check somewhere illogical like the departure terminal.

Comment: I'll try to plan enough time on my return trip to take a longer look then!

Comment: According to the Melbourne airport website there's machines located in T2, T3 & T4 arrivals halls. IIRC there's one in T3 on the ground floor by the main exit doors (top right of T3 area in [this map](http://melbourneairport.com.au/docs/130531-t2-and-t3-(ground-floor)-map.pdf) )

Comment: I couldn't find the T2 one, the T3 one is somewhat hidden but does exist! It's by the toilets and ATMs on the far left just before you leave the baggage reclaim area

Comment: @JoErNanO I added it to my answer instead ;-)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative not mentioned in @Gagravarr's answer is that you can [purchase a myki online](https://www.mymyki.com.au/NTSWebPortal/Common/getmyki/GetMykiOption.aspx?menu=Get%20myki) from the PTV website.

Comment: Where will they post to though? I'm guessing you can't buy online for collection at the airport, or can you?

Comment: No need to "guess"; it's clear from the purchase form.